# PYTHON 3+: How to add a byte into a string without decode

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

### I want to place some bytes into a string.

So I have my string and i want to premend 2 bytes ( the hex value of given number )

```
    given_num = 231
    bytes_num = given_num.to_bytes(2,'big')

    my_str = "abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc"
    my_str = str(bytes_num) + my_str

    print(my_str)
    print(bytes(my_str,'utf-8'))
```

The output is

```
b'\x00\xe7'abc__☺☻♥__abc
b"b'\\x00\\xe7'abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc"
```

I have also tried using the decode method but if a hex value is not 'utf-8'
an error is occured or if I use 'ignore' or 'replace' for error handling it changes the values. It works only if the byte is 'utf-8'.
Also used 'latin1' and 'iso' , same thing.
For exmaple:

```
    given_num = 231
    bytes_num = given_num.to_bytes(2,'big')

    my_str = "abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc"
    my_str = bytes_num.decode("utf-8") + my_str
```

**ERROR:** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1: unexpected end of data

Also tried chr()

```
    given_num = 231

    my_str = "abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc"
    my_str = chr(given_num) + my_str
```

The output again is not the prefered one:

```
çabc__☺☻♥__abc
b'\xc3\xa7abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc'
```

As you can see the first 2 bytes are [0xc3][0xa7] where **i want to see**

```
b'\x00\xe7abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc'
```

(the hex value of given number in bytes)

**In C I would do the above**

```
printf("%c%c some string ",0,231)
```

But this does not work with python format:

```
    my_str = "abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc"
    my_str = "%c" % (231) + my_str
```

The output again tha same, 231 is translated as 2 bytes **[0xc3][0xa7]** instead of one byte hex representation of 231 decimal number **[0xe7]**:

```
çabc__☺☻♥__abc
b'\xc3\xa7abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
def do_stuff(input_str: str, nb1: int, nb2: int):
    return hex(nb1) + hex(nb2) + input_str


print(do_stuff("test", 0, 231))
```

That will result in this string : 0x00xe7test

If you want to use \x instead of 0x notation you can use str.replace or regex to change the resulting string as you wish.

Comment: I need to place he actual byte, not just the hex value. If I do this then the actual result will be "\\x00\\xe7....." I dont care if the byte is printable, and in most cases it is not. I want to have the same result as in C code : printf(" a string with one non-printable byte %c",231)

Comment: Is that better? 
def do_stuff(input_str: str, nb1: int, nb2: int):
    return f"{nb1:x}{nb2:x}{input_str}"


print(do_stuff("test", 0, 231))

You can also use c instead of x to print the byte as char instead of hex value

Comment: This puts the'e7' string.It is like printing the hex value of 231. I want to put the byte with value 'e7' ('\xe7'). This will not print 'e7' in my string because it is not utf-8. For example if i have the byte '\x35' and I place it in a string then the value '5' will be printed , not '35' because 5 is represented with byte 0x35. but 0xe7 hasn't printable character therefor an error occurs

Comment: Did you try the last function with c instead of x  in the formated string ? 

def do_stuff(input_str: str, nb1: int, nb2: int): return f"{nb1:x}{nb2:x}{input_str}" print(do_stuff("test", 0, 231))

I found out you can also use latin1 as encoding to convert the string to bytes like :

print(bytes(do_stuff("abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc", 0, 231), encoding="latin1")) 

This will lead to the same result that you provided in your answer. If your code is enough for what you wanted to do, you can accept your answer to tell the subject is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the "printable" string to bytes 
and then I handled the string as a bytes array

```
    given_num = 231
    bytes1 = b"abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc"
    bytes2 = bytes([0,given_num])
    bytes_res = bytes2 + bytes1
    print(bytes_res)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\xe7abc__\x01\x02\x03__abc'
```